# How can I allow thrown errors to bubble up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When I require a module that throws an error, it ends up returning an empty module instead of allowing that error to bubble up.

My code looks like:

```js
var module = require("./path/to/the-module");
doSomethingWithComponent(module.mainComponent);
```

When there is no error thrown the module looks something like:

```js
{
  getters: []
  actions: []
  mainComponent: <TheComponent />
}
```

When there *is* an error it ends up like:

```js
{}
```

An example of something that breaks the component looks like so:

```js
var TheComponent = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps() {
    return { x: this.props.x };
  }
});
```

Using Chrome's "Pause On Caught Exceptions" option I've tracked down that the exception is happening but it being caught. I'm unable to track down where it's being caught at.

Here's a screenshot of the error happening:

[image: caught error]

Here's a screenshot highlighting how it gets set to an empty object:

[image: webpack empty object]

My webpack config looks like:

```js
var _ = require('lodash');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var vendorLibs = {
  _: 'lodash',
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
  key: 'mousetrap',
  React: 'react/addons',
  debug: 'debug',
  cx: 'classnames',
  Immutable: 'immutable',
  immstruct: 'immstruct',
  interact: 'interact.js'
};
var providePlugin = {
  Mixins: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app', 'mixins', 'index.js'),
  Util: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app', 'lib', 'Util.js'),
  reactor: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app', 'reactor.js')
};

var config = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app/components/App.jsx',
    vendor: _.values(vendorLibs)
  },
  output: {
    path: './src/compiled/js',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /^(?!.*node_modules)+.+\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }, {
      test: /\.json5$/,
      loader: 'json5-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader')
    }, {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!less-loader')
    }, {
      test: /\.png$/,
      loader: 'file'
    }, {
      test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?v=(\d|\.)+)?$/,
      loader: 'file?name=../fonts/[hash].[ext]'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app', 'components'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'less'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'icons')
    ],
    extensions: [
      '', '.jsx', '.js'
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js'),
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin(['main'])
    ),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin(_.extend({}, vendorLibs, providePlugin)),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/app.css', { allChunks: true })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

This app is also using NuclearJS and this component being required is a result of an action being dispatched so it's possible it could also be catching it there.

I'd like this error to not be caught so that I can spot it and resolve it without diving into the debugger. Does anyone know how I can make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a section of code with a try/catch that looked pretty innocent but led to this issue. After I found that I can address the problem. It looked like so:

```
    try {
      require(`modules/${variableValue}/index`);
    } catch (err) {
      dbg(`Cannot load module ${variableValue}`);
    }
```

The `dbg` was not logging in the browser thus I didn't see it.